# Pass PHP5-FPM errors back to error page script?

Tags: nginx, php, php-fpm, php5, 500-error

My `nginx` has an `error_page` setup that throws 500 errors to a PHP page. I wish to display/log any PHP errors that cause this error page to show. When I say display, I mean show in-browser depending on a user's credentials.

**To clarify:** I wish to retrieve the specific details about the exact error that occurred in PHP, not just that there *was* an error.

Is this possible using `PHP5-FPM` and `nginx`?

Comment: How is what you want different than simply disabling `fastcgi_intercept_errors` and letting whatever error output that occurred (assuming appropriate *php* exception/error handler setup and/or *php* display_errors settings) be displayed to the user?

Comment: I want to have the errors hidden from the user if their credentials do not have the appropriate permissions to view errors.

Comment: I don't see how this has anything to do with nginx or php-fpm - your answer appears to be "call `ini_get('display_errors' $canSeeErrors);`" or equivalent.

Comment: How can I call that if the PHP script has errored fatally? To my knowledge I cannot.

Comment: By [using a shutdown function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/277224/how-do-i-catch-a-php-fatal-error).

Comment: I also need to catch (somehow) errors from arbitrary PHP scripts that (whilst I have file access to) I do not have control over. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19017/discussion-between-ruirize-and-ad7six).

Answer (score 2):

As i understand you need to enable `fastcgi_intercept_errors` in your location:

```
fastcgi_intercept_errors on
```

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.html#fastcgi_intercept_errors:

> Determines whether FastCGI server responses with codes greater than or equal to 300 should be passed to a client or be redirected to nginx for processing with the error_page directive.

Comment: The error itself isn't passed to `error_page` as far as I can tell, which means **this approach will not work**.

Comment: What do you mean? Do yo have `display_errors` disabled?

Comment: I want to pass the error to a PHP script for processing.